# insert and insertOne not a function and update not creating mongo ID

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I thought I could read my way to this solution, but I cant see what im doing wrong.

Here is my model:

```
var mongoose      = require('mongoose');
var Schema        = mongoose.Schema;
var inspectSchema = new Schema({
    _id:                Object,     // Mongo ID
    property:           String,     // Property ID
    room:               String,     // The room Name
    item:               Array       // The Items text
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('inspectModel', inspectSchema, 'inspect');
```

And here is where I try to insert or insertOne

```
var inspectModel = require('../../models/inspectModel');
var inspectTable = mongoose.model('inspectModel');

inspectTable.insert(
    {
        "property" : inspectRecord.property,
        "room" : inspectRecord.room,
        "item" : inspectRecord.item
    }, 
function (err, res) {  
    if (err) { return reject({err:true, err:"addInspect ERROR" + err})  }
    else {
        show("=====RESOLVE addInspect=====")
        return resolve();
    }
})
```

I tried

```
inspectTable.insert
inspectModel.insert
inspectTable.insertOne
inspectModel.insertOne
```

No matter what I always get

```
TypeError: inspectTable.insert is not a function
```

I also tried just update with { upsert: true } but then the mongo ID becomes null.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you're looking for is [`create`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#create_create):

```
inspectTable.create(
    {
        "property" : inspectRecord.property,
        "room" : inspectRecord.room,
        "item" : inspectRecord.item
    }, ...
```

However, your schema definition of `_id: Object` is likely wrong. Just leave any definition of `_id` out of your schema and it will use the default `ObjectId`, which is likely what you want.

Comment: That was it Johnny, ObjectId and Object are NOT the same :-D  Couldnt figure out why it wouldnt generate a mongo ID, but now I know.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
var insert_table = new inspectTable(
    {
        "property" : inspectRecord.property,
        "room" : inspectRecord.room,
        "item" : inspectRecord.item
    });
insert_table.save(function (err, res) {  
       if (err) { return reject({err:true, err:"addInspect ERROR" + err})  }
       else {
           show("=====RESOLVE addInspect=====")
           return resolve();
       }
  });
```